# bash check if string contains space

Tags: string, bash

In my bash script I want to check if a string contains a space in it, and if it does replace the space in the string with `%20` to parse the string to a website.

I'm very new to bash, what should be the best way?

I know how to to this in c# but bash is a little different I see.

Comment: Replace the *space*, not the string, I assume?

Comment: Only a space (to `%20`)? Mind that for the *percentage encoding*, there are other characters that need to be encoded as well...

Comment: Yes, only the space in the string.

Comment: But that makes your encoding one way, because if the original string says 'I got 20%20', it will encode to `I%20got%2020%20`, and you cannot know where the last `%20` originates from.

Comment: Yes, but for my purpose (request input mode on a denon receiver) this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do with `sed` [inside a shell script]:

```
#!/bin/bash -

str="abc def ghi"
echo "$str"

hstr=`echo "$str" | sed -e 's/ /%20/g'`
echo "$hstr"
```

Answer (score 3):

See "Shell Parameter Expansion" in the bash manual.

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

For your case, assuming a variable named x,

```
$ x="one two three"

$ echo $x
one two three

$ echo ${x// /%20}
one%20two%20three
```

(*edit: linked to gnu.org bash manual)

Answer (score 2):

On Debian and Ubuntu, one can install the `gridsite-clients` package:

```
sudo apt-get install gridsite-clients
```

This package ships with a command called `urlencode` that encodes strings using the *percentage encoding*. This goes a bit beyond what you ask, because the percentage itself for instance, is encoded as well (to `%25`).

For instance:

```
$ urlencode "foo bar"
foo%20bar
$ urlencode "foo%bar"
foo%25bar
$ urlencode "foo-bar/baz"
foo-bar%2Fbaz
```